# How to fetch Square Inventory By SKU using PHP?

Tags: php, square

I want to fetch all products from Square Catalog.

Here is the code:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Square\SquareClient;
use Square\LocationsApi;
use Square\Exceptions\ApiException;
use Square\Http\ApiResponse;
use Square\Models\ListLocationsResponse;
use Square\Environment;


$client = new SquareClient([
    'accessToken' => '{{access_token}}',
    'environment' => Environment::SANDBOX,
]);


//Providing SKU
$object_ids = ['GFLR20L', '232GGGD'];
$body = new \Square\Models\BatchRetrieveCatalogObjectsRequest($object_ids);
$body->setIncludeRelatedObjects(true);

$api_response = $client->getCatalogApi()->batchRetrieveCatalogObjects($body);

if ($api_response->isSuccess()) {
    $result = $api_response->getResult();
} else {
    $errors = $api_response->getErrors();
}
```

Output:

```
object(Square\Models\BatchRetrieveCatalogObjectsResponse)#13 (3)
```

```
{
  ["errors":"Square\Models\BatchRetrieveCatalogObjectsResponse":private] => NULL
  ["objects":"Square\Models\BatchRetrieveCatalogObjectsResponse":private] => NULL
  ["relatedObjects":"Square\Models\BatchRetrieveCatalogObjectsResponse":private] => NULL 
}
```

**> Post Suggestions by sjosey:

> My PHP Code:
>
> Looking for Products with name Paper in it.**

```
$object_types = ['ITEM'];
$prefix_query = new \Square\Models\CatalogQueryPrefix('name', 'paper');

$query = new \Square\Models\CatalogQuery();
$query->setPrefixQuery($prefix_query);
```

**>     Storing Values Here**

```
$body = new \Square\Models\SearchCatalogObjectsRequest();
$body->setObjectTypes($object_types);
$body->setQuery($query);
$body->setLimit(100);

$api_response = $client->getCatalogApi()->searchCatalogObjects($body);
```

**> Fetching the api response here**

```
if ($api_response->isSuccess()) {
    $result = $api_response->getResult();
} else {
    $errors = $api_response->getErrors();
}
```

**>     Echo Result**

```
var_dump($result);
```

**Here is the output:**

```
object(Square\Models\SearchCatalogObjectsResponse)#15 (5) { ["errors":"Square\Models\SearchCatalogObjectsResponse":private]=> NULL ["cursor":"Square\Models\SearchCatalogObjectsResponse":private]=> NULL ["objects":"Square\Models\SearchCatalogObjectsResponse":private]=> NULL ["relatedObjects":"Square\Models\SearchCatalogObjectsResponse":private]=> NULL ["latestTime":"Square\Models\SearchCatalogObjectsResponse":private]=> string(20) "1776-07-04T00:00:00Z" }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the solution. The following codes fetches a list of all the products by Product IDS. The array can be used to set data as per requirements (By SKU or Anything)

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Square\SquareClient;
use Square\LocationsApi;
use Square\Exceptions\ApiException;
use Square\Http\ApiResponse;
use Square\Models\ListLocationsResponse;
use Square\Environment;

$client = new SquareClient([
    'accessToken' => '{{access_token}}',
    'environment' => Environment::PRODUCTION,
]);


$bag = [];
$cursor = null;
$ctr = 1;

$api_response = $client->getCatalogApi()->listCatalog($cursor, 'ITEM');

if ($api_response->isSuccess()) {
    $result = $api_response->getResult();
} else {
    $errors = $api_response->getErrors();
}

$g1 = $result;
$g2 = json_encode($g1);
$g3 = json_decode($g2);
$cursor = $g3->cursor;
$objects = $g3->objects;
$g4 = json_encode($objects);
$g5 = json_decode($g4);

foreach($g5 as $g51){
    $bag[$g51->id] = $g51;
}





while($cursor != null){

$api_response2 = $client->getCatalogApi()->listCatalog($cursor, 'ITEM');

if ($api_response2->isSuccess()) {
    $result2 = $api_response2->getResult();
} else {
    $errors2 = $api_response2->getErrors();
}

$g6 = $result2;
$g7 = json_encode($g6);
$g8 = json_decode($g7);
$cursor = $g8->cursor;
$objects2 = $g8->objects;
$g9 = json_encode($objects2);
$g10 = json_decode($g9);

foreach($g10 as $g101){
    $bag[$g101->id] = $g101;
}

}



var_dump(count($bag));
```

Answer (score 0):

`object_id`s are not the same as SKU; they are unique generated ids on Square's side. You would want to use the [SearchCatalogObjects](https://developer.squareup.com/reference/square/catalog-api/search-catalog-objects) (POST /v2/catalog/search) endpoint instead to search by SKU. An example query using one of your SKUs would be:

```
{
  "query": {
    "exact_query": {
      "attribute_name": "sku",
      "attribute_value": "GFLR20L"
    }
  }
}
```

This will get your catalog object ids, but if you're interested in the inventory you would still need to use another endpoint to get the inventory, such as [RetrieveInventoryCount](https://developer.squareup.com/reference/square/inventory-api/retrieve-inventory-count) (which takes the `catalog_object_id`'s as the parameter).

Comment: Tried implementing the Search option. Have updated the question. Is my process wrong?

Comment: All the fields in the response are private in the PHP SDK so you must use getters/setters. In your case, I think you'd want to do something like `$result->getObjects()[0]->getId()` would get the id of the first catalog object in the result. Since it's an array, you'd probably want some kind of loop functionality though.

Comment: That gives this as output: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getId() on null in /path/index.php:93 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /pathe/index.php on line 93; 93 is where i am using $result->getObjects()[0]->getId();